# Does htaccess password keep search engines out?

Tags: htaccess, search-engines

I had a mishap when a site on my staging server was picked up by Google.  I want to devise a foolproof but simple strategy to prevent this from happening again. 
Would password protecting the entire subdomain with htaccess prevent Google from being able to index a site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a WP question, but I do this with dev sites. I don't think I can give you an absolute answer as to search engines' behavior, but speaking from experience, adding authentication like htpasswd retroactively would cause an *eventual* departure from search results. Adding auth proactively has produced effective results for me. The search engine hits the auth, then is left with a 401 error.

You can also try asking Google to in-undex your stuff if you need to. The site needs to be registered in Google Websmater Tools/Search Console. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking only of protective implementation.

Comment: *proactive  (typo)